# Difference between Birt data cubes vs mondrian pentaho data cubes

Tags: eclipse, pentaho, data-cube

I have used Eclipse birt data cube but didn't gain any performance improvement over a huge data. Could i get any performance improvement if i use mondrian data cubes. 
What is the main difference between *Eclipse birt data cube* and *mondrian data cubes*.

Answer (score 0):

Different Engine. Mondrian cubes come from Pentaho.  A ROLAP cube won't necessarily give you an immediate huge improvement - what is it you're looking for?  The main advantage of cubes is caching ( which will obviously help - but no use when cold ) and ability to process the data in a businesslike way.

Saying that Mondrian is very good and has a lot of performance related features - especially agg tables..  Mondrian is also used in a lot of other BI suits and follows industry standards ( olap4j/mdx/xmla etc)

Perhaps if you have a specific data problem more info on that could help devise a solution!

You may also want to look at an analytic db, combine Mondrian or any cube with one of those and you'll fly.